# How to get local music information in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am gonna build Xamarin.Forms app which will read music information like the artist's name and song's name from local music file.
Is there any way to do that?

Actually I need to get local music files like iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for the Xamarin Media Manager to play music and videos using Xamarin.Forms

https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

You can combine this with a local file reader and away you go.